# Match a string pattern from other data.frame

Tags: regex, r, merge, dataframe, pattern-matching

Suppose I have two dataframes a and b,
a has one column called 'detail':

```
pure water
wood fire
mineral water
water
fire work
```

and b has one column called 'type':

```
water
fire
```

Many R functions require input text to get match, grep('fire',a), but my question is if there is a way to match a using b?  I tried loop but failed. Following SQLDF got all false result for match.

```
ab <- sqldf(select *,case when detail in (select distinct types from b) then 1 else 0 end as match) from a)
```

Ideally, one can using something like `c <- grep(a$detail,b$types)`. not sure if it is allowed in R though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could your provide an actual example of your data?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am new here, so just create a markdown example. http://rpubs.com/songlh15/22723

Answer (score 1):

Create a `type` column in `a` and then merge on it:

```
merge(transform(a, type = sub(".* ", "", a$detail)), b, all = TRUE)
```